# Return statement unexpectedly closes the application

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1

    Function UnexpectedInput(y, x)

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Input ! ( " & y & " ) ")
        Console.WriteLine("Please Try Again...")
        Console.ResetColor()

        Console.WriteLine("")
        Return x

    End Function

    Dim choice As String

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Please Register to use this program. If you already have an account please choose Loign.")
        Space(1)
        Console.WriteLine("1. Login ")
        Console.WriteLine("2. Register ")
        Console.WriteLine("3. Exit ")
        Space(1)
        Console.WriteLine("##########################")
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("##########################")

        If choice = "1" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Login()")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf choice = "2" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Register()")
            Console.ReadLine()
        ElseIf choice = "3" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Exitnow()")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            UnexpectedInput(choice, "Main()")
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

The return x doesn't work it just closes the application. I had it working and now it doesn't work. I'm completely stuck and I'm a newbie.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when it ***does*** work?  It looks like the only thing that would return is the string "main()"

Comment: I want it to go back to Main()
I want to use it so show the user what he inputted that was unexpected and return it back to the sub it was on

Comment: Then you need a loop to do that.  Loop until some condition is satisfied.  How did you have it working before?

Comment: I don't know, for example if choice = 4 then it would print to the console whats in the function and then return to the sub that it was in , which I defined in x

Comment: "x" is just a string.

Comment: but when I put Main() it says that I wont return a value? All I want to do is make a function where I can show the user what the last input was and then return it back to the sub that it came from

Comment: I think you are trying to create a loop so it goes back to the menu on an incorrect input, if so, consider using `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you, I have just hard coded it instead XD

Comment: Also - please fix your tags - you're not using VBA

Answer (score 0):

> The `return x` doesn't work it just closes the application.

Well, of course it does. It is returning from the `UnexpectedInput` function, back to `Main`, and then the `Main` subroutine completes, thus causing your application to automatically close. You should have been able to figure this out for yourself, by thinking through the logic of the code. Even if you couldn't do this tracing completely in your head, you could have done it with the aid of the debugger built into Visual Studio by single-stepping through your code. (This is a fantastic way to practice, and essential for debugging hard problems.)

In `Main`, you have the following If construct:

```
    If choice = "1" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Login()")
        Console.ReadLine()
    ElseIf choice = "2" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Register()")
        Console.ReadLine()
    ElseIf choice = "3" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Exitnow()")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        UnexpectedInput(choice, "Main()")
    End If
```

If the input is neither 1, 2, nor 3, then the `Else` clause will be entered. That will cause the `UnexpectedInput` function to be called, effectively jumping execution to that point. Code will start running here:

```
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Input ! ( " & y & " ) ")
    Console.WriteLine("Please Try Again...")
    Console.ResetColor()

    Console.WriteLine("")
    Return x
```

This will print some stuff to the console, and then return the value `x` to the caller.

Going back to the caller:

```
UnexpectedInput(choice, "Main()")
```

you'll notice that the caller completely ignores the function's return value. It doesn't assign it to a variable for later use, nor does it use it directly. It just throws it away, just like it were a `Sub`, rather than a `Function`. This is totally allowed, and the compiler won't even issue a warning if you ignore the return value of a function. You need to check for this yourself, by reading and understanding the flow/logic of the code.

After executing and returning from `UnexpectedInput`, the flow of control continues in the `Main` subroutine. Except that there is no other code in the `Main` subroutine to execute! The If construct ends, and then the `Main` ends. Once `Main` ends, according to the rules of the VB.NET language, the entire program ends. Thus, the runtime library automatically closes your application.

If your problem is simply that the console window is closing too quickly for you to see the output, then you can solve that problem by running the application with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. This launches the program without the debugger attached, and will *not* allow the console window to be automatically closed. Instead, it will wait for you to press a key before it gets closed.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, if you wish to allow the user to enter another choice when their first one was invalid, then you'll need to wrap the If construct in a loop. A While loop works well; consult your favorite reference on VB.NET programming for more information. Break out of the While loop when encountering valid input; otherwise, continue looping until valid input is encountered (or the user selects to exit).